# Issue upgrading ember 2.8 to 2.11 - cannot find module 'ember'

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I believe this is somehow related to how Ember is now setup through npm instead of bower.

After upgrading my application (working fine previously on lts 2.8) to 2.11 using this process:

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v2.11.0

I was relatively meticulous incorporating the diffs while going through `ember init` and have checked my app against the current ember-cli blueprint for 2.11:

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/tree/v2.11.0/blueprints/app/files

And yet upon load I get in the console:

`Uncaught Error: Could not find module 'ember' imported from '(require)'`

I noticed bower.json still had `"ember": "lts-2-8"` in it, but removing it seemed to have no effect.

Is there some other step now that `ember` is installed through npm?

From package.json:
`"ember-cli": "2.11.0"`
`"ember-source": "^2.11.0"`

EDIT:

ember-let seemed to cause one of these errors, but even with removing this from package.json, still seeing this one:

````
```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember` imported from `*/app`
    at missingModule (loader.js:239)
    at findModule (loader.js:250)
    at Module.findDeps (loader.js:190)
    at findModule (loader.js:253)
    at requireModule (loader.js:20)
    at app-boot.js:4
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving `ember-cli-shims` from `bower.json` to `package.json`

You can very well check and confirm for the changes between 2.8 to 2.11.
https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/compare/v2.8.0...v2.11.0

Comment: well, that at least *changed* the error message, which I suppose means it addressed this and exposed another issue: 
`Could not find module ember-htmlbars/helpers
   ... 
   at resolveInitializer (index.js:5)`

Comment: check `package.json` file contains `"ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.1.1",`

Comment: it does, I'm combing through the doc you linked to to see if some other version mis-match is at play

Comment: a-ha, had to upgrade ember-microstates, it was relying on some foregone internal ember module, using 0.3.0 now and we're good, thank you!